# How to improve my error handling of this chain of promises?

Tags: node.js, typescript, error-handling, promise, command-line-interface

I am new to TypeScript/JavaScript and Node.js and coming from Java/Scala background.
I am writing a simple script in `TypeScript` to collect some data and send them as an HTTP POST request to a server using `axios`.

```
makePromiseToGetA()
  .then((a: A) => makePromiseToGetB(a))
  .then((b: B) => sendHttpRequestAxios(b))
  .then((resp: AxiosResponse) => outputResponse(resp))
  .catch((err: Error) => handleError(err))
```

Now I want to improve the error handling. Specifically, I want to handle `AxiosError` using my function `handleAxiosError(ae: AxiosError)` *in addition* to the generic error handling (function `handleError`)

Now I see two options to do that:

1. Modify the `handleError` function like this:

   ```
   // pseudocode because I don't know how to code this in TypeScript

   function handleError(err: Error): void { 

     if (err instanceof AxiosError) {
       handleAxiosError(err as AxiosError);
     }
     ... // handle Error
   }
   ```
2. "catch" `AxiosError` after `sendHttpRequestAxios`, handle the error, and then re-throw it:

   ```
   makePromiseToGetA()
     .then((a: A) => makePromiseToGetB(a))
     .then((b: B) => sendHttpRequestAxios(b).catch((ae: AxiosError) => {handleAxiosError(ae); throw ae;}))
     .then((resp: AxiosResponse) => outputResponse(resp))
     .catch((err: Error) => handleError(err))
   ```

How would you suggest handle `AxiosError` with `handleAxiosError` *in addition* to generic error handling using `handleError` ?

Comment: I landed here because I was looking for a way to check in an Error is an axios error or just a regular one. I found `axios.isAxiosError(err)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your #1 seems like a reasonable solution to me if you generally want to handle `AxiosError` instances differently from other errors. The problem with #2 is that you'll end up handling the error twice: Once in the Axios-specific rejection handler and then again in `handleError`.

If you don't like that `instanceof` approach (in `handleError` or in the rejection handler at the end), you can use nesting:

```
makePromiseToGetA()
  .then((a: A) => makePromiseToGetB(a))
  .then((b: B) =>
    sendHttpRequestAxios(b)
      .then((resp: AxiosResponse) => outputResponse(resp))
      .catch((err: AxiosError) => handleAxiosError(ae))
  )
  .catch((err: Error) => handleError(err))
```

That takes advantage of the fact that the Axios part is the last non-rejection part of the chain. So you handle it via `handleAxiosError`, converting rejection to fulfillment — but nothing uses the resulting fulfillment, so you're good. If some *other* error occurs, though, you end up in the final rejection handler.

---

Side note: It's just an example and your real code is probably more complex (though perhaps the rejection handlers aren't), but when passing a fulfillment value or rejection reason to a function as its argument, there's no need for a wrapper arrow function:

```
makePromiseToGetA()
  .then(makePromiseToGetB)
  .then((b: B) =>
    sendHttpRequestAxios(b)
      .then(outputResponse)
      .catch(handleAxiosError)
  )
  .catch(handleError)
```

Comment: Thanks ! I don't like my #1 mostly because it makes "generic" `handleError` "know" about specific errors in the chain.

Comment: I like the `catch(handleAxiosError)` you suggested but in this case `handleAxiosError` should also invoke `handleError`, which is probably Ok ...

Comment: @Michael - Oh! I assumed that was undesirable behavior. :-) My bad.

Comment: :)) I probably was not clear. I will emphasize that  `handleAxiosError` should be done _in addition_ to `handleError`.

Comment: Anyway, I think you are right that "re-throwing" is not the best solution.

Comment: @Michael - If you want both `handleAxiosError` and `handleError` to be triggered, re-throwing (your #2) seems just fine to me.

Comment: If `handleAxiosError` is true to its name, then surely it should see only errors thrown by `sendHttpRequestAxios()`, not those thrown by `outputResponse()`.
Therefore `.then((b: B) => sendHttpRequestAxios(b).then(outputResponse, handleAxiosError))`. Alternatively unnest `.then(outputResponse)` and leave `.catch(handleAxiosError)` behind (similar to the question's option 2).